# Flatness of schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, deformation-theory, flatness

I am learning about flatness for the first time and I cannot wrap my head around why the definition with tensor products of a flat module implies geometrically that 1-parameter families of schemes have limits.

I came across these lecture notes by Alexander Ritter which give a very explicit example:

[image]

However, I don't understand why $\pi$ flat over $0 \iff$ $X_0$ is $\lim_b X_b$. Any help to understand this particular example or a different intuition of this geometric implication would be very much appreciated.

Comment: For me, it helps to show that the limit statement is equivalent to the fact that no irreducible or embedded component of $X$ is supported on the fiber $X_0$. Then you can "see" that flatness looks like the absence of "vertical" components, so it literally looks flat. Also I think all of these equivalences need some assumption on the base $B$, like regularity.

Comment: In the setting of those notes, for $X = \operatorname{Spec}(A)$, by definition, the closure of $X^*$ is $\operatorname{Spec}$ of the image of $A$ in $A[t^{-1}]$. The map from $A$ to $A[t^{-1}]$ is injective if and only if there's no element in $A$ annihilated by $t$, which is the same as $A$ being flat over the DVR $k[t]_{(t)}$.

Comment: You can look in Mumford, The red book of varieties and schemes (2nd edition), III.10 for geometric intuition. See especially Proposition 1 and Examples Q and R, for which you can work out the characterisation mentioned in Ritter's notes.

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault Example Q and R are not satisfactory — they are consequences of Proposition 2, which says that a finitely presented module is flat if and only if it is locally free, but this is not usually how flat families appear (usually very non-finite). By the way, the 2nd edition is not really a new version, but a worse version than the 1st — it introduces a lot of typos during TeXification.

Comment: This is also proposition 9.7, Hartshorne chapter 2, where he proves (rather tersely) that a punctured one parameter flat family fills up uniquely as the (scheme theoretic) closure.

Comment: @Z.M My comment was probably not formulated correctly. I was just saying you can check whether this continuity condition holds in these particular examples. (In example R, the base is not the affine line, but you can restrict the base to a line like ↦(,,). The base change of a flat morphism is flat, so you can detect non-flatness in this way.)

Answer (score 4):

Note that $\overline{X^*}$ is the scheme-theoretic image of $X^* \to \mathbf A^n_B$: if $X^*$ is reduced, this agrees with the reduced induced structure (see for instance exercise II.3.11 in Hartshorne), and otherwise this is the only sensible definition of the closure of a locally closed subscheme.

In particular, if $X^* \subseteq \mathbf A^n_{B^*}$ is cut out by some ideal $I^*$, then by definition $\overline{X^*} \subseteq \mathbf A^n_B$ is cut out by the contracted ideal $\overline{I^*} = \iota^{-1}(I^*)$, where $\iota \colon B[x_1,\ldots,x_n] \to B^*[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ is the inclusion. In other words, the factorisation $X^* \to \overline{X^*} \to \mathbf A^n_B$ corresponds to the image factorisation
$$B[x_1,\ldots,x_n] \twoheadrightarrow B[x_1,\ldots,x_n]\big/\ \overline{I^*} \hookrightarrow B^*[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/I^*$$
of rings.

Any module $M$ over the principal ideal domain $B$ is flat over $0$ if and only if it is $t$-torsion-free. Since $B^*[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/I^*$ is a $B^*$-algebra, the element $t$ is invertible there, so $B^*[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/I^*$ is always flat over $0$. Thus, $B[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/\overline{I^*}$ is also flat, since a submodule of a $t$-torsion-free module is $t$-torsion free.

So if $I \subseteq B[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ is an ideal and $I^*$ its extension to $B^*[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$, then we certainly see that $I = \overline{I^*}$ implies that $B[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/I$ is flat. Conversely, we always have $I \subseteq \overline{I^*}$, and the kernel of
$$B[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/I \twoheadrightarrow B^*[x_1,\ldots,x_n]\big/\ \overline{I^*}$$
is $t$-torsion since this map becomes an isomorphism after inverting $t$. Thus, we see that $B[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/I$ is $t$-torsion-free if and only if $I = \overline{I^*}$.

Of course there is nothing special about $B[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$, and the same argument works for any $B$-algebra $R$ (or $B$-scheme $Y \to \operatorname{Spec} B$).